# php if pg true show button on navigation bar

Tags: php

I want a button to show on my navigation bar only if the page `is = to employees`.

I was doing this to accomplish this.

on employees.php

```
<?php $pg = employees; ?>
```

on header.php

```
<?php
if ($pg == $employees) 
?>
<?php
     <a class="btn btn-info" href="https://www.ebillity.com/Firm4.0/Login.aspx?CorpLogin=1">Time Sheets</a>
?>
```

Here is the error im getting in the browser

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/lpnew/includes/header.php on line 60
```

Comment: `=` sets, `==` (or `===`) *compares*. You want the latter.

Comment: Shouldn't the first assignment be `$pg = $employees`?

Comment: I do not understand why this question was down voted... Either way. I edited with the == in my code and the error i'm getting in the browser.  I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You've got an opening `<` inside the second PHP block. You don't need to wrap HTML inside PHP tags

Comment: would you mind posting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done some typing errors, so you have got an error

on employees.php

```
<?php $pg = $employees; ?>
```

on header.php

```
<?php
if($pg == $employees){
?>
 <a class="btn btn-info" href="https://www.ebillity.com/Firm4.0/Login.aspx?CorpLogin=1">Time Sheets</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @NichoDiaz : I didn't do anything much. It was just a small mistake from your side.

Comment: I appreciate that. It so funny They downvoted my question and someone upvoted it back. I don't see why most people have to be so rude about things. If someone doesn't want to answer my question why cant they just move on? haha thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because you aren't using echo on your link and you need to swap your double quotes for single quotes.

Try this for your link:

```
echo "<a class='btn btn-info' href='https://www.ebillity.com/Firm4.0/Login.aspx?CorpLogin=1'>Time Sheets</a>";
```

It looks like your if statement is not finished either you don't have anything in {}. It also appears you are trying to call the current page? I'm making a few assumptions but try this:

```
if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])== 'employee.php'){
    //do something
}
else{
    //do something else
}
```